# Rails/Bootstrap/css/Responsive image sizing small

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel from bootstrap which is working fine above `min-width: 768px`

The images scale to 100% width of the container which is full page.

What I would like to do, is as the page goes below say 500px in width: fix the height of the images so that they still scale in width, but don't go over a certain height. I'm happy if they are cropped during this process. Any ideas on how I might do this using only css or .erb tags

Many Thanks

Comment: Good to be post your code? so anyone can help.

Comment: Maybe you could use background images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using the @media css property: [Link to instructions.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

You can then specify max-width of 500px in the @media property and set the max-height property of image to what you want it to be. You would need to include this in your own stylesheet so that it overrides the bootstrap css.

Comment: ThanksSion that is what I needed. Took me a while to figure it out even with the instructions. But i needed to switch from min-width, which I was using for the larger sizes to max-width for the smaller size. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

There is amasing class calling `img-responsive` in bootstrap, use it with your images. It may resolve your problem.

More you can find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp).